# $E[\varphi(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_t] = \varphi(E[X_t| \mathcal{F}_t]) $ implies adaptedness?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I am stuck on the following problem: 
Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process. We have that for all $\varphi$ that are continuous and bounded it holds:

$$E[\varphi(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_t] = \varphi(E[X_t| \mathcal{F}_t])   $$

where $\mathcal{F}_t$ it is some filtration. Then it follows that $X_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ adapted. 
I am pretty sure that I've already seen this result somewhere but at the moment I cannot figure out where. May be someone here can give me a hint or a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $t$ is fixed and will play no role, I'll drop it from the story. Thus we have an integrable random variable $X$ such that $E[\varphi(X)|\mathcal F]=\varphi(E[X|\mathcal F])$ for all bounded and continuous $\varphi$. I will allow $\varphi$ to be complex-valued. (Look at the real and imaginary parts of $\varphi$ separately and then add.) Let's define $Y:=E[X|\mathcal F]$. Now take $\varphi(x) = \exp(i\lambda x)$ in the basic identity, multiply both sides by $\exp(-i\lambda Y)$, and then take expectations. There results
$$
E[\exp(i\lambda(X-Y))]=E[\exp(i\lambda Y)\exp(-i\lambda Y)]=1,
$$
which is true for all real $\lambda$. What does this tell you about the random variable $X-Y$?

Comment: $E[exp(i\lambda (X-Y)]$ is the characteristic function of X-Y. As it is 1 i can conclude that $X-Y \sim \delta_0$, so X-Y is distributed just as a pointmass in 0. Thus X has the same distribution as $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$ which holds iff X is $\mathcal{F}$ measurable. Or am I interpreting it in the wrong way? I had the idea to look at the 'sequence' of distributions of $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$ which converges weakly to X iff $E[\varphi(X)] = E[\varphi(E[X|\mathcal{F}])]$ for all  $\varphi$ bounded and continuous.   But that's just a different way of getting that they have the same distribution, right?

Comment: More precisely, because the distribution of $X-Y$ is the point mass at $0$, you have $P(X=Y)=1$, so $X=E[X|\mathcal F]$ a.s.